# MovieClip references going awry in onLoadComplete callback

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I'm loading a bunch of images into my AS2 flash movie, and I've encountered some strangeness.

Roughly, my code looks like this:

```
function doTheLoading()
{
    m_imageClips = [];

    for (var i:Number = 0; i < 3; i++) 
    {
        var imageUrl:String = "http://server/" + i + ".jpg";

        var mc :MovieClip = m_mc.createEmptyMovieClip("name"+i, i + 1);

        m_imageClips.push( mc );

        var mcLoader:MovieClipLoader = new MovieClipLoader();
        mcLoader.addListener(this);
        mcLoader.loadClip(imageUrl, mc);
    }

    myDebug("array1: "+m_imageClips);
}


function onLoadComplete(mc:MovieClip)
{
    myDebug("array2: " + m_imageClips );
    myDebug("type: " + typeof(m_imageClips[0]) );

    for (var i:Number = 0; i < m_imageClips.length; i++) 
    {
        if (mc == m_imageClips[i]) 
        {
            /* This line is never reached. */
        }
    }
}
```

And the output looks something like

```
array1: mc.0.jpg, mc.1.jpg, mc.2.jpg
array2: ,,
type: movieclip
array2: ,,
type: movieclip
array2: ,,
type: movieclip
```

So my question is why does my array content seem to change when in the onLoadComplete call? If the array is out of scope, then why can I still see the length of the array and determine the type of the contents?

Answer (score 0):

The bit of code you posted works fine when I run it, so I think your problem must be somewhere else. Can you post any more of your code?

---

As an aside, [Ross's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2409741/movieclip-references-going-awry-in-onloadcomplete-callback/2411230#2411230) suggests that there's a scope problem, but it's a bit more complicated than that...

It's not quite true to say that **m_imageClips** is out of scope: if you haven't declared **m_imageClips** (with a `var` statement) before you assign it the value of `[]`, then it will be declared automatically.

> Many  programming languages require
>   variables to be declared before data
>   may be deposited into them; failure to
>   do so would cause an error.
>   ActionScript is not that strict. If we
>   assign a value to a variable that does
>   not exist, the interpreter will create
>   a new variable for us.
>   *- (Colin Moock, Actionscript the Definitive Guide)*

In this case, it will be declared within the scope of the main timeline, so it will be available to both the `doTheLoading()` and `onLoadComplete()` functions. Hence the code runs fine as you've shown it.

This also means that if you do want to use Ross's solution (with a `return` statement etc), you need to declare **m_imageClips** to be local to `doTheLoading()` by using **`var`**`m_imageClips = [];` inside that function. Kind of doubling-up though, since you end up in the same place...